# On the inequality $p^{\alpha +1}q^{\beta +1}-2p^{\alpha+1}q^{\beta}-2p^{\alpha}q^{\beta +1}+2p^{\alpha}q^{\beta}+p^{\alpha+1}+q^{\beta+1}-1 > 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers

I'm working on some equations in number theory and I stuck on below inequality :

$$p^{\alpha +1}q^{\beta +1}-2p^{\alpha+1}q^{\beta}-2p^{\alpha}q^{\beta +1}+2p^{\alpha}q^{\beta}+p^{\alpha+1}+q^{\beta+1}-1 > 0$$

Here $p$ and $q$ are distinct prime numbers and $p,q >2$ and $\alpha\,,\beta$ are positive integer numbers.

Can somebody help me to prove that or find counterexample , although I believe that the inequality is true.

Comment: Are $\alpha,\beta$ real or integer numbers?

Comment: @ÁngelValencia: integer number

Comment: Are they positive?  Non negative?  Or arbitrary integers?  Please edit this into the question.

Comment: @ErickWong : sorry , I edited .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LHS is $$x y (\;(p-2)(q-2)-2\;)+p x+q y-1$$ where $x=p^a$ and $y=q^b$. Since $p,q$ are distinct odd positive integers, $(p-2)(q-2)\geq 3.$

Comment: Looks very much like my final answer…

Comment: @Bernard :  Thank you both

Answer (score 4):

Factor  $p^{\alpha +1}q^{\beta +1}-2p^{\alpha+1}q^{\beta}-2p^{\alpha}q^{\beta +1}+2p^{\alpha}q^{\beta}$ as 
$$p^\alpha q^\beta(pq-2p-2q+2)=p^\alpha q^\beta\bigl((p-2)(q-2)-2\bigr),$$
hence
\begin{align*}&p^{\alpha +1}q^{\beta +1}-2p^{\alpha+1}q^{\beta}-2p^{\alpha}q^{\beta +1}+2p^{\alpha}q^{\beta}+p^{\alpha+1}+q^{\beta+1}\\
{}={}&p^\alpha q^\beta\bigl((p-2)(q-2)-2\bigr)+p^{\alpha+1}+q^{\beta+1}.
\end{align*}
Now, if $p,q>2$, $p\ne q$, the first term in the above sum is $\ge 0$, and $p^{\alpha+1}+q^{\beta+1}\ge p+q \ge 8 $ since $p,q$ are distinct odd primes.

Comment: That doesn't look right to me: $\cdots+p+q)$ should be $\cdots+\frac{p}{q^\beta}+\frac{q}{p^\alpha})$, shouldn't it?

Comment: Your factorization is wrong.

Comment: @Bernard It is wrong for the reason TonyK says.

Comment: @TonyK: That was a silly mistake. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Take $p=q=\alpha=\beta=3$. We get $$3^{8}- 4\cdot 3^{7} + 2 \cdot 3^{6} + 3^{4} + 3^{4}-1=-568$$

Comment: $p$ and $q$ are distinct .

Comment: @A-M: WRONG! Correct is: "Oh, I'm sorry $-$ I forgot to say that $p$ and $q$ are distinct. I will edit my question immediately."

Comment: @TonyK : Oh, I'm sorry − I forgot to say that p and q are distinct. I will edit my question immediately.